# Efficient algorithm for comparing one-on-one tournaments

Tags: algorithm, sorting, design-patterns

I was thinking of doing a simple program, which basically has a list of some items - such as foods, for an example - and which pairs two foods against each other for user to choose his or her favourite out of those two options. Ultimately, a list of ranked candidates would emerge. Behind the scenes, I thought two really simple "algorithms" to work by.

1. Working through each pairing possible to score the list perfectly. Seems really tedious for the user when there are many items in the list.
2. Simple elimination. Two foods enter, one leaves for the next round. But I can't really then get a rank, other than just general estimates of categories of performance.

So I was wondering, what other ranking systems there would be for one-on-one "tournaments" like this?

Comment: I think that when it comes to taste, this king of algorithm is going to be hard to get right. Consider this, you have apples, oranges, and bananas. You want to rank them according to a persons taste choices, so you ask what is best, apples or oranges. Person responds apples. Then you ask, oranges or bananas, the person responds oranges. Then you ask, apples or bananas, the person responds bananas. So now you have a cycle, no clear ranking, as the order would be "apples > oranges > bananas > apples". Commutative taste is not a thing.

Comment: In real tournaments, it's implied that if you pit X against Y and Y against Z, and Y wins over Z and X wins over Y, then X also implicitly won over Z, without having to compete, because the choices are commutative. I don't think this necessarily applies to taste. If I like apples over oranges, it doesn't mean I like apples over everything that I like oranges over.

Comment: The only way, probably, to get a real ranking system in this kind of situation would be to first present **all** the options to the person, and ask them to pick 1, as in "what would you rather pick". Then remove that option from the list and ask again, "now what would you rather pick", and then keep going until you have only one option left which is the last one.

Comment: I would recommend reading about the ELO rating system: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system
Rating systems of this kind are used in tournaments of this kind and have the benefit that you don't need to calculate every possible pairing, but the more comparisons you do, the more precise the rating will be. If you plan to have different people participate, you may need some customisation though.

Comment: *"then X also implicitly won over Z, without having to compete, because the choices are commutative"* I assume you meant **transitive** and not **commutative**? But actually, in real tournament, it's well-known that this is false; in fact, the main argument to avoid pitting X against Z in that situation is specifically to avoid a (likely) cycle X > Y > Z > X which would make it harder to decide a winner.

Comment: You might be interested in research papers: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=tournament+ranking

Comment: People's choices are not necessarily coherent, so you can't reduce n×(n-1)/2 matchs to a signle order. I developped a software many years ago fir an HR consultancy looking for suc incoherences to rate candidates

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a ranking with few comparisons, it will be very hard to beat [Merge-Insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge-insertion_sort).  It is seldom used in practice because it is a lot of work to figure out the next comparison to make.  But computer time is cheap relative to human time, so putting in the work to reduce the work on the human is worthwhile.